# How to correctly call useFetch custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a react project where I have created an API and that I want to use for my react project, I'm dealing with react hooks and not able to call API correctly. I have tried couple of things, but I keep getting one or other kind of error.

Latest method I have tried is giving me this error

> Line 8:20:  React Hook "useFetch" is called in function "filterList" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Code for filterList.js look like this

```js
/* to filter the products based on the categories */

import useFetch from './apiService'

export default function filterList(arr, method, courses) {

    const URL = "http://localhost:8000/api/getCourses";
    const result = useFetch(URL, {});

    courses = result;

    console.log(courses, 'Inside filterList')

    if(method == null) return courses;

    else {
          return courses.filter(course => {
          const categoryArray = course.category.split(" ");
          if(arr.length > 0) {
                if(categoryArray.some(r => arr.indexOf(r) >= 0)) {
                    return course;
            }
          }
          else {
              return courses;
          }
          return courses;
      })  
    }
}
```

and code for apiService.js where I have created useFetch function look like this

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

// to fetch the data from api
 const useFetch = (url, defaultData) => {
    const [data, updateData] = useState(defaultData);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchData() {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const json = await response.json();
        updateData(json);
      }
      fetchData();
    }, [url]);
  
    return data;
  };

export default useFetch;
```

Please let me know what is the thing that I'm doing wrong and what should be correct method to do this.

Comment: As it is said you can only call hooks inside components and other hooks. So, you need to rename `filterList` to be `useFilterList`. And make sure that `useFilterList` is also only used in hooks or components.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko -  In this case I'm using `filterList` in App.js which is again defined as function `const App = () => { ... }` so if I change this to `useFilterList` it will throw me same error, right? In this case how to make this working?

Comment: It should not. Give it a try. Hooks are defined by having `use*` prefix.

Comment: I did and it's throwing me same error. I'm using this in `useEffect(() => {
    setCourses(useFilterList([], null));}` in App.js. Anything that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong. `() => {..}` is yet another function that neither component nor a hook.

Comment: So what should I do in this case. I'm kind of lost. I want to use this in `const App = () => { ... }`

Comment: Also I'm referring to [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-demo-u7xd9?file=/src/index.js) example if it helps. Even after implementing same way I'm getting above error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225327/discussion-between-marwari-and-yury-tarabanko).